# SharePoint 2010 - CustomAction for Files and Folders

Tags: sharepoint, custom-action

I have a very basic question about CustomActions in the Elements.xml, I have successfully created a little application that ads an item in the Context Menu for my document libraries for files, my goal is to have this same Custom Action available for Files and for Folders, so far it is only working for Files when I'm using  the RegistrationID=**"0x0101"** and for folders **"0x0120"**

I would like to have my solution properly working for both types.

Here is my Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction      
        ScriptSrc="/_layouts/CustomContextMenu/Permissions.js"
        Location="ScriptLink"
        Sequence="100">
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="CustomContextMenu.MenuItemClicked"
                RegistrationType="ContentType"
                RegistrationId="0x0101"   
                Location="EditControlBlock"
                ImageUrl="/_layouts/CustomContextMenu/security-key.png"
                Title="External Access"
                Description="This options allows you to configure the access to this item for external users">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:PermissionsDialog('{SiteUrl}', '{ItemId}', '{ListId}');" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Location="EditControlBlock"

  RegistrationId="101"

RegistrationType="List"

  RequireSiteAdministrator = "False"

  Rights = "AddListItems"    

  Description="Custom Upload"

  Title="Move To"   >
```

This works for me both folders and files.